# VBA - Final Column Select and Export

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and I want to do the following:

I am inputting data for different materials, I will add new materials daily, a new column for each new material.

What I want to do then, is select ONLY the latest column entry, and export that as a .txt file.

I have managed to export the entire worksheet, but have not yet managed to find how to export only the latest "entry" of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This code based on example publicated John_w at https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-export-a-specific-worksheet-to-txt-file.754163/#post-3703300 and adapted to your case:

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub SaveLastColumn()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Worksheets(1).UsedRange           ' get an area with data on the sheet
    Set rng = rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count)    ' get the last column inside rng
    
    Open "File.txt" For Output As #1            ' open text file for output
    
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then                 ' rng can contains 1 or many cells
        Dim arr As Variant                      ' in case of many cells
        arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
        Print #1, Join(arr, vbCrLf)             ' write many values to file
    Else                                        ' in case of 1 cell
        Print #1, rng.Value                     ' write single value to file
    End If
    
    Close #1
End Sub
```